# The set of strict maximums or strict minimums of an arbitrary function is countable.

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

The set of points where an arbitrary function $f: X \to \mathbb{R}$ defined in a set $X \subset \mathbb{R^m}$ admits a strict maximum or minimum is enumerable.

[Hint: Let $E \subset X$ be a dense enumerable subset. For each point $x \in X$ that is a strict maximum of $f$, choose $e_{x} \in E$ and $r_{x} \in \mathbb{Q}$ with $|e_{x} - x| <r_{x}$ and $y \in B(e_{x}; r_{x}) - \{x\} \Rightarrow f(y) < f(x)$. The application $x \mapsto (e_{x}, r_{x})$ is injective].

I have the following proof but I don't know if it is correct because $ f:X \to \mathbb{R}$ and $X \subset \mathbb {R^m}$. What do you think about this test?:

Let $M$ be the set of strict local minima of a function $f$. Then for every $p\in M$ there is an open interval $(a,b)$ such that $f(p)$ is smaller than $f(x)$ for any $x\in(a,b)\setminus\{p\}$. We can now choose rational numbers $a_p,b_p$ with $a<a_p<p<b_p<b$, and $f(p)$ will be the smallest value on $(a_p,b_p)$.

Define a map $g:M\rightarrow\Bbb Q^2$ taking $p$ to a pair $(a_p,b_p)\in\Bbb Q^2$ like above. It's clear $g$ is injection, since $f(x),f(y)$ cannot both be smaller than each other for $x\neq y$. Hence $g$ is an injection into a countable set showing $M$ is countable.

Could another demonstration be better than this one?